# 100 million people vaccinated in 100 days?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, joe-biden, vaccine

[article here](https://nypost.com/2021/01/24/fauci-joe-bidens-100m-shots-does-not-mean-100m-people/)

The Biden administration is trying to dampen expectations about the vaccine. But, the numbers still don't add up. If 100 million shots are administered, some of those shots will go to people who have gotten only one shot. Let's say that is 10 million. Then, the remaining 90 million shots will be distributed 2 shots each to 45 million people. That is not 67 million people vaccinated. The absolute maximum number of people that could be vaccinated with 100 million shots is 50 million. Where does the 67 million number come from? They do not intend to count people who were already vaccinated (two shots) or had one shot already before Biden was inaugurated, do they?

It seems like Tony Fauci is trying to clarify something about what the 100 million vaccines actually means, but he actually created more confusion to me.

I believe this is a political question because the handling of covid-19 and the vaccine has been a major political issue in the campaign and the debates, etc.

Comment: not all vaccines require two doses, J+J alone is expected to have 100M single-dose treatments available by april (day 111). Biden's goal is quite modest, but the harder they make it sound now, the more political capital he gains with success.

Answer (score 8):

The Post article seems to misinterpret the [actual quote from Face The Nation](https://mobile.twitter.com/FaceTheNation/status/1353375934481526784): the goal is 100M doses, which will represent 67M people receiving at least one dose.

> 100 million injections totals *about* 67 million people, Dr. Anthony Fauci explains to @margbrennan

> Some will have received one dose of the vaccine, others both doses, he says.

From that we can calculate that during the 100 days, the plan is for approximately  33M people to get 2 doses and 34M will receive 1 dose - either their first dose, with a second coming outside that window, or their second dose, with the first taking place before the start of the window

Comment: Plus, not all vaccines require two doses, some only one dose, and at least one requires two shots but only a half dose for the first shot.